# How to sort column from table in CSV file in PHP?

Tags: php, csv, sorting, html-table

I try to sort my second column from my CSV file in PHP.
I do this code for sorting, but I don't get the sorting, this is my code:

```
    if (($handle = fopen($address_book, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $text_to_html = "<table border='1'>";
    $sum = array();


    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000)) !== FALSE) {
        array_push($sum, $data[0]);
        array_push($mdarray, $data);
        $num = count($data);

        //echo "<p> $num fields in line <br /></p>\n";
        if ( $data[0] == "first_name" ) {
            //first loop of while will print table header
            $text_to_html .=  "<tr><th>";
            for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                //echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
                $text_to_html .= $data[$c] . "</td><td>";           
            }
            $text_to_html .= "</th></tr>";
        } else {
            $text_to_html .= "<tr><td>";
            $first_name = $data[0];
            $last_name = $data[1];
            $text_to_html .= $last_name . "</td><td>";
            $text_to_html .= "</td></tr>"; 
        }


    }
       fclose($handle);
       foreach ($mdarray as $key => $row) {
       $names[$key]  = $row[1];
 }
 array_multisort(array_column($mdarray, 1), SORT_ASC, $mdarray);
```

Thanks :)

Comment: When are you expecting the data to be sorted, it looks as though you sort it after displaying the information in this code.

Answer (score 0):

Just declare $mdarray as an array outside the while loop as shown below and check,

```html
if (($handle = fopen($address_book, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $text_to_html = "<table border='1'>";
    $sum = array();
    $mdarray = array();

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000)) !== FALSE) {
        array_push($sum, $data[0]);
        array_push($mdarray, $data);
        //....other code....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors in your code.

First is: You have not declared `$mdarray` as array(). Without declaring array, array_push will not work.

Second is: You have not closed the foreach loop at end, closing brace is missing here.

```
foreach ($mdarray as $key => $row) {
       $names[$key]  = $row[1];
```

After solving these errors, you will get sorted array.